# If $F(x,y)$ vanishes at $(a,b)$, then the first term in its Taylor series is the product of tangents?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose $F(x,y)$ is a smooth function. The linear term of its Taylor series about $(a,b)$ is $$F_x(a,b)(x-a)+F_y(a,b)(y-b)$$ which also happens to describe the tangent line at $(a,b)$ to the curve implicitly given by $F(x,y)=0$, provided one of the partials does not vanish.

However, it may happen that both the partials vanish at that particular point and so no tangent line is obtained. But what I noticed is that for polynomial functions passing through the origin, the lowest degree term is the product of 'tangent-like' lines to the curve drawn at the origin. My questions are :

1. Why is this happening for polynomial functions?
2. Does this happen for general smooth functions?

I mentioned the first term in the Taylor series since it would be the lowest degree term (which I observed to be the case for polynomial functions).

Comment: You'll want to look up "tangent cone" for question 1. For question 3, what do you mean? We need $F(a,b)=0$ to talk about the point $(a,b)$ being on the curve and tangent directions to the curve at that point - what would you do if $F(a,b)\neq 0$? (One option is to consider the set given by $F(x,y)=F(a,b)$, but it's not clear that this is what you want.)

Comment: @KReiser I didn't think clearly while typing it. I've edited it out now.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_theory may be relevant (in the case you are looking only at functions on the plane, this was studied by Hassler Whitney). But I am not sure I understand your description. When you say that you are looking at polynomial functions through the origin, do you include cases where the origin is a local minimum?

Comment: @WillieWong I only mean that the origin is a "point on f" i.e. the graph of the function passes through the origin.